# Highcharts Pie chart with CSV data

Tags: csv, highcharts

I am building a set of dynamically loading highcharts with CSV data. I am having one big issue with the pie chart: when  the chart is a pie chart, labels are not appearing and all I see is the word "Slice". Any other type of chart is loading the data as I expect.

Specifically I've noticed this is where "Slice" is coming from, but I'm uncertain how to control it:

```
        pointFormat: '<tr><td>{series.name}:</td>'...,
```

The second more obvious issue is I'm having trouble setting up an example on jsfiddle to share my issue.

This works locally on a MAMP server:

```
    var graphData = 'data04.csv.html';
```

This is not working:

```
    var graphData = "Unused-Entry,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\nPercentage of marketshare,5,5,5,5,5,5,15,15,15,25";
```

It appears that I either need a different CSV formatting or I need to pre-processs it differently but I cannot figure out how.

here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mntfk9gp/

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/7/ This example seems to be accomplishing both things I am unable to get working.

Comment: Well, for its working (http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/10/) with yor data which you refer. So how can I replicate this issue?

Comment: Yes that example is working, the issue is in the jsfiddle I made ( http://jsfiddle.net/mntfk9gp/ ), i can't figure out why mine isn't working. Mine works great locally on a MAMP server and can pre-processes a CSV for bar or line charts without a problem. I can't figure out why the other examples work with a string instead of a csv.

Comment: Ok, I replaced everything inside the working example with my code except for the preprocesser and it now works. http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/14/ Unfortunately I did not learn why. I think I'll be writing an if statement so then if the type of chart is pie, use preprocessor A, else use preprocessor B.